# Keeping this tag is an in[justice]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, burninate-request

There are <strike>56</strike> <strike>31</strike> 10 questions tagged with [justice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice)

Most of the questions seem to be about [law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) or [crime](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime) or [corruption](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corruption) where the asker seems to think that "Justice has not been done", and therefore tagged it with "justice" too.

- [Henry Kissinger and the International Criminal court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39362/henry-kissinger-and-the-international-criminal-court)
- [What is the status of former Brazilian president Michel Temer prosecution for corruption charges?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53890/what-is-the-status-of-former-brazilian-president-michel-temer-prosecution-for-co)
- [Did the US Floyd protests actually result in charges against the police officers involved](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53838/did-the-us-floyd-protests-actually-result-in-charges-against-the-police-officers)
- [Is it typical for someone to be arrested over $20k violation of campaign finance laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/is-it-typical-for-someone-to-be-arrested-over-20k-violation-of-campaign-finance)

Other questions use it to describe the [Criminal Justice system in general](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25640/are-minorities-given-harsher-sentences-in-the-criminal-justice-system-in-the-us)

There are also a few questions referring to [the Justice Department](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33269/can-donald-trump-fire-someone-who-works-in-the-justice-department) or the [Ministry of Justice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21773/why-do-countries-maintain-a-ministry-of-justice) and a few questions referring to Supreme Court [Justices](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61527/how-immune-are-supreme-court-justices-or-other-high-ranking-judicial-officials-f).

---

The usage of the tag is too broad and unspecific to be useful. In addition, it seems to encourage questions about whether a ruling or a system are "Just" which is opinion-based and therefore off-topic.

I'd argue that the tag should be removed or be made a synonym of [law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law), with some questions being retagged to [justice-department](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice-department), [supreme-court](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supreme-court), or [judiciary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judiciary)

---

Since this has been open for 6 days with no objections, I've started to do some of the manual retagging. Once that's done we can set up the tag synonym

Comment: This is the first use of the tag [burnation-request], so I wrote a tag wiki about what I think it means. Also, is this tag a synonym of [tag-synonyms] and if not how is it different?

Comment: @Yay Thanks for pointing that out. It's a term used on stack overflow, but I hadn't realized that it wasn't used here. I've created a tag wiki based on the Stack Overflow version

Comment: @Yay To your second question, a [burninate-request] is related, but broader. I think [justice] should be a synonym of [law] in general, but there are many questions that shouldn't be tagged [law] or need to be otherwise retagged as well

Comment: @Yay As divibisan pointed out making a synonym can involve a lot of cleanup work before you to it so that questions don't get a tag they shouldn't have. Also just because tags are somewhat related doesn't mean one should be a synonym of the other.

Comment: I retagged some more. I think it's fine to make it a synonym of [law] now. Feel free to reply to this comment if you (dis)agree.

Comment: @JJJ Looks fine to me. I think all the remaining questions are fine, tag-wise at least. Synonymize away!

Comment: @divibisan *"Tag Synonym justice -> law was approved!"* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JJJ, this issue has been resolved. Questions have been retagged as needed and the synonym request was approved.

Thanks!